# Regex to represent "NOT" in a group

Tags: java, regex

I have this Regex:

```
<(\d+)>(\w+\s\d+\s\d+(?::\d+){2})\s([\w\/\.\-]*)(.*)
```

What I want to do is to return FALSE(Not matched) if the third group is "MSWinEventLog" and returning "matched" for the rest.

```
<166>Apr 28 10:46:34 AMC the remaining phrase
<11>Apr 28 10:46:34 MSWinEventLog the remaining phrase
<170>Apr 28 10:46:34 Avantail the remaining phrase
<171>Apr 28 10:46:34 Avantail the remaining phrase
<172>Apr 28 10:46:34 AMC the remaining phrase
<173>Apr 28 10:46:34 AMC the remaining phrase
<174>Apr 28 10:46:34 Avantail the remaining phrase
<175>Apr 28 10:46:34 AMC the remaining phrase
<176>Apr 28 10:46:34 AMC the remaining phrase
<177>Apr 28 10:46:34 Avantail the remaining phrase
<178>Apr 28 10:46:34 AMC the remaining phrase
<179>Apr 28 10:46:34 Avantail the remaining phrase
<180>Apr 28 10:46:34 Avantail the remaining phrase
```

How to put "  **NOT** '`MSWinEventLog`' " in the regex group `([\w\/\.\-]*)`  ?

Note :
The second phrase above should return "not matched"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<(\d+)>(\w+\s\d+\s\d+(?::\d+){2})\s(?!MSWinEventLog)([\w\/\.\-]*)(.*)
```

a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (here: '**`(?!MSWinEventLog)`**') should be enough:

> Negative lookahead is indispensable if you **want to match something not followed by something else**.
>   When explaining character classes, I already explained why you cannot use a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match a "q" not followed by a "u". Negative lookahead provides the solution: `q(?!u)`.

Comment: Haha
This is the exact answer that I want. Anyway Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with negative lookahead:

```
<(\d+)>(\w+\s\d+\s\d+(?::\d+){2})\s(?!MSWinEventLog)([\w\/.-])(.)
                                   -----------------
```

`(?!MSWinEventLog)` will match only if not *immediately followed by* an expression matching "MSWinEventLog".